# What is the meaning of "nothing on the line"?

Tags: meaning

Snow (Prisoner) appointed to get President's daughter, Emily,
who get held in MS One space prison station. Snow saw his 
friend, Mace, died infront of him.

> Snow: Who cares? People die all the time. It's no big deal. How many
>   people have died for you since you got here? But you're the
>   President's daughter, so you're worth it, right? Looks like your
>   little PR trip got all screwed up.
>
> Emilie :I came here to ensure that people were being treated fairly
>   and decently, unlike yourself.
>
> Snow: You know, it's easy to be a saint with **nothing on the line**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*On the line* is an expression adopted long ago from gambling: *the line* is the area or mark where currency or tokens are placed in making a bet.

So to have something *on the line* means you are risking loss of the amount you have bet, and to have *nothing on the line* means that you have not made a bet and therefore have nothing to lose.

Snow thus says that Emilie's virtuous intentions are existentially trivial, because they isn't risking any loss.